# Remove Gridlines from Google column chart

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am using the google column chart from this example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

and I want to remove the horizontal gridlines, after searching for apparently below is supposed to make them invisible (I tried with `hAxis` too) but it does not seem to be effecting the chart at all...

```
vAxis: {
    gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
    }
}
```

Why is this not doing anything?

Comment: That example uses the old and deprecated `columnchart` package.  Change the `google.load` call to use `corechart` instead to get access to the modern charts.  Your gridline options should work then.

Comment: @asgallant well that 1 hour of my life I wont get back ha. Thanks that fixed the problem

Comment: Google could - at some point - update their examples!

Answer (score 4):

This will work for sure:

```js
vAxis: {
   minValue: 0,
   gridlines: {
     color:'transparent'
   },
}
```